# use many processes to filter a million records

Tags: python, multithreading

I have python script that works well for a few numbers:

```
def ncpr (searchnm):
  import urllib2
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  mynumber = searchnm
  url = "http://www.domain.com/saveSearchSub.misc?phoneno=" + mynumber

  soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
  header = soup.find('td', class_='GridHeader')

  result = []
  for row in header.parent.find_next_siblings('tr'):
      cells = row.find_all('td')
      try:
          result.append(cells[2].get_text(strip=True))
      except IndexError:
          continue
  if result:
    pass
  else:
    return str(i) 


with open("Output.txt3", "w") as text_file:

  for i in range(9819838100,9819838200):
    myl=str(ncpr(str(i)))
    if myl != 'None':
        text_file.write((myl)+'\n')
```

It checks the range of 100 numbers and return the integer that is not present in the database. It takes a few seconds to process 100 records. 
I need to process a million numbers starting from different ranges. 
For e.g.

```
9819800000 9819900000
9819200000 9819300000
9829100000 9829200000
9819100000 9819200000
7819800000 7819900000
8819800000 8819900000
9119100000 9119200000
9119500000 9119600000
9119700000 9119800000
9113100000 9113200000
```

This dictionary will be generated from the list supplied:

```
mylist=[98198, 98192, 98291, 98191, 78198, 88198, 91191, 91195, 91197, 91131]
mydict={}

for mynumber in mylist:
  start_range= int(str(mynumber) + '00000')
  end_range=int(str(mynumber+1) +'00000')
  mydict[start_range] = end_range
```

I need to use threads in such a way that I can check 1 million records as quickly as possible.

Comment: You'll want to move your imports to outside of `def ncpr()`, otherwise they will be called 1 million times. Generally a good idea to minimize code in a loop.

Comment: just one question. if your job could be divided into sub tasks, are they independent?

Comment: Yes. As you can see the series numbers do not over-lap each other. The output file (Output.txt3) too can be separate if required. But a single file is easier to download.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is not so much about how to parallelize it, but about the fact that you query a single number per request.  This means processing a million numbers will generate a million requests, using a million separate HTTP sessions on a million new TCP connections, to `www.nccptrai.gov.in`.  I don't think the webmaster will enjoy this.

Instead, you should find a way to get a database dump of some kind.  If that's impossible, restructure your code to reuse a single connection to issue multiple requests.  That's discussed here: [How to Speed Up Python's urllib2 when doing multiple requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009243/how-to-speed-up-pythons-urllib2-when-doing-multiple-requests)

By issuing all your requests on a single connection you avoid a ton of overhead, and will experience greater throughput as well, hopefully culminating in being able to send a single packet per request and receive a single packet per response.  If you live outside India, far from the server, you may benefit quite a bit from HTTP Pipelining as well, where you issue multiple requests without waiting for earlier responses.  There's a sort of hack that demonstrates that here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576673-python-http-pipelining/ - but beware this may again get you in more trouble with the site's operator.